# Can I use wildcards in Windows 8 search?

Tags: windows-8, search

When using a new Windows 8 search bar:

[image: search bar]

What is the syntax of the search expression? Is it possible to use wildcards like "*", "?" or any other special symbol?

For example, when searching with Google i can use:

- '**-**' (minus) for excluding certain words;
- "quoted phrase" for exact phrase matching.

Answer (score 13):

Windows 8 has a number of search features.

It supports two wildcards.

```
*   match anything
?   match any character
```

You can search by:

- file extension

  ```
  Ext:.txt
  ```
- date

  ```
  Date:This week
  ```
- type

  ```
  Kind:Folder
  Kind:Document
  ```
- filesize

  ```
  Size:>10mb
  ```
- author

  ```
  Author:="Joe Bloggs"
  ```

More information at: http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/windows_8_search-indexing_files-windows_explorer_ribbon-advanced_query_syntax,2-228-2.html

Comment: Whoa!  Now I can increase my Search-Fu within Windows 8.

Answer (score 4):

You can still search using the [Advanced Query Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711(v=VS.85).aspx).

I recommend reading the article because there are a lot of features.

Here are some of the boolean operators:
[image: AQS Boolean Operators]

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should be able to use the same wildcard codes that were usable in Windows 7 since the "type to search" feature is nearly identical in both. Here's a link that describes some of the codes. It describes wildcards and search codes.

http://www.winextra.com/tech/software/windows-7-search-wildcards-and-search-codes/

An extract from the site

> **Wildcards**
>
> This option has been with us since the earliest days of DOS and
>   Windows and consists of two wildcards: ‘?’ and ‘*’ (without the single
>   quote marks). The simplest explanation to what the two different
>   wildcards do boils down to this: the ‘?’ means one character appears
>   here and the ‘*’ can stand for any number of characters – letters or
>   numbers.
>
> So if you are using the ‘?’ and you are searching for a file that you
>   know part of the name of your query could look like this fo??t which
>   would return any file that started with fr and ended with a ‘t’ but
>   only had two unknown letters in the middle. In this case the file
>   foxit could be one of the search results.
>
> When using the ‘*’ as part of the search term it is best to use it
>   either at the beginning of the word – *it – or in the middle – f*t –
>   in either case the file named foxit would be returned as part of the
>   results. As for using the ‘*’ wildcard at the end of the search term
>   there isn’t much of a point because Windows search always acts like
>   there is a wildcard at the end.
>
> **Search Codes**
>
> The one thing about the way I usually end up doing searches is that I
>   typically end up with way more results than I really need. The way
>   around this happening is to use search shortcuts – or codes – to
>   further refine what you are searching for.
>
> The simplest of these is the document types short codes. For example
>   you are searching for a specific image but you forget its name but
>   remember that it is a JPEG (jpg) image. In this case you can use the
>   following short codes to refine your search
>
> ```
> ext: .jpg
> fileext: .jpg
> extension: .jpg
> filextension: .jpg
> ```

**UPDATE:** Also check out this site: http://www.7tutorials.com/basics-making-advanced-searches-wildcards-and-filters