# Is it possible to make Windows 8 searches more advanced?

Tags: windows-8, windows-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use wildcards in Windows 8 search?](https://superuser.com/questions/496188/can-i-use-wildcards-in-windows-8-search)

I know that I can easily search for a document -- provided I can remember what I named it or a non-common word it contains -- by typing on the Tiles ("Metro") screen (or by mashing Windows key + F from the desktop), but I'd like to be able to start the search at a particular spot, or at least provide a date range to search (like the "old-fangled" way of searching, in XP, for example). I like being able to supply vals such as "C:\ImportantStuff*.pdf" between (today) where file contains the phrase "the sun shines bright on my old Kentucky home" (or whatever).

### UPDATE

What I'd like to do is to be able to search for the contents of a file, e.g., if I know it contains the text "SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += OnSettingsPaneCommandRequested;"

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell.  'Yes, you can use many advanced searches'  I would start with keywords such as: 'Size', 'Date Modified' or 'Kind'

For example Size:>10mb.

If you use the boolean operators make sure you type them in UPPER CASE

OR, 
AND, 
NOT

Comment: Rock on , just was i was about to reply :)

Answer (score 1):

You can even search files effectively with command prompt if you find the default search as in effective. Very less people know this but it is very convenient. http://www.funbutlearn.com/2012/08/the-easy-way-to-search-files-search.html

Comment: Hi! Link-only answers aren't considered real answers. Please post the relevant contents here, on-site. Also, your Super User account shouldn't just be used to advertise your (?) blog.