# Wildcards in Windows 8 search

Tags: windows, windows-8, search, wildcards

I already read this question:
[Can I use wildcards in Windows 8 search?](https://superuser.com/questions/496188/can-i-use-wildcards-in-windows-8-search)
but it doesn't answer mine.

It seems to me, that the wildcards (especially `*`) are not consistently working correctly.

Assume I have a file with the name `abc_d270_def_1000.fun`.
When I search in the Windows 8 Explorer for `*000.fun`, it doesn't find this file. But in Windows 7 the exact same search string does find this file.
I did a bit of investigation and discovered that my file won't be found when I'm searching for

```
abc_d*70_def_1000.fun
abc_d**0_def_1000.fun
```

but it will be found when I'm searching for

```
abc_d***_def_1000.fun
abc_d2**_def_1000.fun
abc_d27*_def_1000.fun
```

So it seems that the wildcards can not be placed before a number.

Is there a way to change this, so that I can search for `*000.fun` and my file will get found?

Comment: I've seen similar. I'm wondering if it has to do with the file extension being an unrecognized type.

Comment: Are you sure `abc_d***_def_1000.fun` worked?  Because that contradicts your theory about wildcards working only when they follow a digit.

Comment: Yes I'm sure that `abc_d***_def_1000.fun` worked. It doesn't contradict my theory. I'm sorry that I misexpressed my theory. I didn't want to say that Wildcards are working only when they follow a Digit, rather than saying that Wildcards are not working when they are placed before a number. (It's kind of the negative way).